# How am I supposed to validate this custom matcher in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I have started studying Rspec recently and a got a challenge to solve: Do an object capable of recognize some keys using Regex.

The object needs to pass in a bunch of Rspec tests.
Here are some examples:

```
describe '#phone?' do
context 'when receive a valid phone' do
  [
    '+55861107350',
  ].each do |key|
    context "when key is #{key}" do
      let(:key) { key }

      it { is_expected.to be_a_phone }
    end
  end
end

context 'when receive an invalid phone' do
  [
    '55861107350',
    'jake@gmail',
    '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000'
  ].each do |key|
    context "when key is #{key}" do
      it { is_expected.not_to be_a_phone }
    end
  end
end
```

What I'm not getting is how am I supposed to validate the be_a_phone matcher, since in the challenge says I can only modify the class file(which is empty and I need to create)

I have been researching about custom matchers and the way you define a custom matcher is by creating the method in another spec file, and supposedly I'm not allow to do that.

Can I make a Rspec::matchers.define :be_a_phone inside a class? or a class file?

My class(it's very raw):

```
    # frozen_string_literal: true

class Key
    attr_reader :key, :type
    
    def initialize(key)
        @key = key.to_s
        @type = ''
        self.define_type
        
    end

    def set_key(newKey)
        @key = newKey
    end

    def set_type(newType)
        @type = newType
    end


    def define_type

        if self.key.scan(/^\+[1-9][0-9]\d{1,14}$/)[0] == self.key
            puts "Your key is a valid Phone"
            self.set_type("phone")
            return "valid"
        return self.set_key("invalid")
        
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the question. Do you ask how to write `be_a_phone` matcher so that predefined specs pass? Or how to do it using plain Ruby object instead of RSpec DSL?

Comment: Is there a way to do it with plain object? I think that would help me, i will search about that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Example (first found) https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-custom-rspec-matchers-to-specify-behaviour

Comment: I think you are looking for predicate matchers. You can learn more about them here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers